# WPF is not in Microsoft Expression Blend

Tags: blend

Good afternoon everyone, my problem is that I wanted to work with Microsoft Expression Blend 4 and WPF, but when creating a new project does not appear type WPF projects, not if I have to install some kind of extension or what the problem is . Greetings. Sorry if my English is bad

Comment: Which version of Expression Blend do you have installed?

Comment: Microsoft Expression Blend 4

Comment: There's Expression Blend that comes with Visual Studio Pro, Expression Blend for Phone, and Expression Blend for Silverlight. Do you have the version that comes with Visual Studio?

Comment: When I install visual studio 2012 is installed automatically blend

Comment: The version that comes with VS 2012 is Expression Blend 5, not 4. Did you do a default install of VS?